# AH00124 error due to something in the .htaccess

Tags: php

I have the following in my `.htaccess` file to strip all of the .php extensions of the files.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
  RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
```

But every now and then, I get the following error in my Apache logging:

```
[core:error]   AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

But I can't seem to find out why.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: “*Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.*” Have you considered heeding the advice you’ve been given here?

Comment: Yes, but I couldn't get that to work properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expected `</IfModule>` before end of configuration!!

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
  RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
</IfModule>
```